# Two date picker are not aligning properly with respect to each other android

Tags: java, android, datetimepicker, timepicker

I am using two time pickers to set a start time and an end time. But in some devices I am facing a problem that both time picker alignments are not the same. The selected time in both the time pickers show the text but they're not properly aligned.

I have also seen my layouts but they are all correct. The biggest thing is that I am facing this problem in some of the devices not in every device.

My Layout xml is:

https://docs.google.com/document/d/12zYYIDHTK3AgN_0OSkAzLvFVcpVpdlYt5lSPDIYqg7M/edit?usp=sharing

I am facing this problem in samsung galaxy tab 3.

Comment: show us the xml layouts and tell us what devices you get the problem. What do they have different than others working ok? maybe smaller resolution?

Comment: My Layout xml is :

https://docs.google.com/document/d/12zYYIDHTK3AgN_0OSkAzLvFVcpVpdlYt5lSPDIYqg7M/edit?usp=sharing

I am facing this problem in samsung galaxy tab 3

Comment: My date time picker class is https://docs.google.com/document/d/1s9aahTxQ7-UCQY6UCwaHvj6PWbYVIk4tCF7I03jFjUM/edit?usp=sharing   . U can check that also. Thanxx

Comment: It would be helpful to post the code here so we don't have to switch back and forth.  Just a suggestion...

Comment: actually when i use this date time picker in my other devices then both the pickers data are alligned properly bt when i use this in samsung galaxy tab 3 then it shows that issue. So i think its not my xml issue. But not confirmed. Please help

Comment: @KristyWelsh Thanx for your suggestion but actually i was new to stackoverflow so i am facing problem in posting my code here thats why i am using google drive. Sorry for inconvenience...

Comment: @TarandeepSingh the code is missing in the post itself, the illustration link is dead: overall, your question is incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

The xml layout you give us has 2 NumberPicker elements with visibility "gone"
I presume that at some point you make the third NumberPicker visible.

In the above case the second NumberPicker has

```
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
```

and the third does not. This might be causing you the alignment problem

Comment: thanx but the issue not this as i have made 2 number pickers visibility gone as i am making it visible through code as per requirement. And for gravity and layout_gravity i was trying to center its data inside but that didn't work. So if u remove this then even it doesnt make any difference..

Comment: try also making the layout_width the same to all three. And try to fix your layout with all three Visible and then do it Gone to see if this creates any problem